# for loop execution fails since the variable i won't increment, reaosn why?

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NO_OF_STUDENTS 4


int main() {
    char c;
    int i;
    char * names[5];
    names[0] = "Jane";
    names[1] = "Jim";
    names[2] = "Jacques";
    names[3] = "Juan";
    names[4] = "Junlian";


    for (i = 0; i <= NO_OF_STUDENTS; i++);
        if (i = 0)
            printf("Front of the Line: %s\n\n", names[i]);
        else
            printf("Followers: %s\n\n", names[i]);

    scanf("%c", &c);

}
```

im trying to make the loop work, however the loop would just fail at front of the line: Jane and it would just fail to proceed to **else**.

can anyone tell me why the loop would just fail and variable i would stay at 0 and not increment in order to display other names?

Comment: hint: `for (i = 0; i <= NO_OF_STUDENTS; i++);` this is already the complete loop including the body. Sometimes a single `;` matters a lot :P

Comment: `if(i = 0)` should be `if(i == 0)`

Comment: add "==" instead of "="


= means assigning values

Always use {} brackets for loops, any kind of

Comment: First, you have 5 students, but NO_OF_STUDENTS is 4. Second, in the for loop, remove `;` at its end. Third, in if statement, you want a comparison, not an assignment

Comment: @lucas  Why did you decide that your program is a C++ program and not a C program?

Comment: wow, so many errors - it's like an interview question :)

Comment: thank you for the helps!

Comment: btw in some circles this is frowned upon, but its a neat trick to prevent such assignment instead of comparsion errors: Use yoda notation, `if (0 == i)`, if you get it wrong and type `if (0 = i)` you will get a nice compiler error

Comment: `i` is not incrementing because you are reassigning `0` to `i` in if `(i = 0)`. Change it to if `(i == 0)` and i will increase. Also remove semicolumn after for loop. You also need to have `scanf` in the loop if you want to get input data. Not sure what are you doing with variable `c`?

Comment: @tobi303 Not that bad this is.

Comment: @tobi303 many compilers these days will also complain about `if (i = 0)` with the right warning level: `error: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Werror=parentheses]`

Comment: In your `for` loop, the condition should be `i < NO_OF_STUDENTS`.  If you have 5 students, the array slot 5 is not valid, so not `<=` but `<`.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it is a C program and not a C++ program (as you marked it) because the compiler should at least issue a warning that the declaration of the array `names` does not have qualifier `const` because in C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays.

```
const char * names[5];
^^^^^
```

The program has two bugs. The first one is the presence of a semicolon at the end of the for statement

```
for (i = 0; i <= NO_OF_STUDENTS; i++);
                                    ^^^
```

And the second one is using the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator in the if statement

```
    if (i = 0)
         ^^^
```

There is no relation between this manifest constant

```
#define NO_OF_STUDENTS 4
```

and the declaration of the array

```
char * names[5];
```

So the constant itself and the number 5 look like magic numbers.

You could declare the array and initialize it simultaneously.

A corresponding C program can look at least the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NO_OF_STUDENTS  5

int main(void) 
{
    char c;
    int i;
    char * names[NO_OF_STUDENTS] =
    {
        "Jane", "Jim", "Jacques", "Juan", "Junlian"
    };

    for ( i = 0; i < NO_OF_STUDENTS; i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 0 )
            printf( "Front of the Line: %s\n\n", names[i] );
        else
            printf( "Followers: %s\n\n", names[i] );
    }

    scanf( " %c", &c );

    return 0;
}
```

Or the program can be written like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char * names[] =
    {
        "Jane", "Jim", "Jacques", "Juan", "Junlian"
    };
    const size_t NO_OF_STUDENTS = sizeof( names ) / sizeof( *names );   

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < NO_OF_STUDENTS; i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 0 )
            printf( "Front of the Line: %s\n\n", names[i] );
        else
            printf( "Followers: %s\n\n", names[i] );
    }


    char c;
    scanf( " %c", &c );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the `if` and `else` could also do with some `{}` love

Comment: @Caleth As for me myself then I use {}. But I tried to use the style of the author of the question.